# Wi-Fi networks not detected anymore

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

### **Problem :**

Wi-Fi networks not detected anymore

### **What triggered it ?**

My computer froze and I ended up having to restart it using the power switch.
In case it could be relevant : it froze while I was using Calc, trying to drag and drop items (bug already filed in LibreOffice).

### **What have I attempted to solve it ?**

I was under Kubuntu 13.10 when it happened, so I took this opportunity to reinstall the OS with Kubuntu 14.04 (no config files were kept), but it didn't solve it.

### **Current diagnosis :**

When running "sudo iwlist wlan0 scan", "wlan0 No scan results" comes up.

The /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state shows :

- NetworkingEnabled=true
- WirelessEnabled=true
- WWANEnabled=true
- WimaxEnabled=true
- WiMAXEnabled=true

### **What could I try ?**

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue. http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a hardware problem more than a software one : I ended up resetting the BIOS to the default settings, but doing this wasn't enough : **unplugging the charger cable and removing the battery before restarting my computer was needed** too.

Maybe if I had just tried removing the battery and charger, without resetting the BIOS fist, it would have been enough (since I can't remember having made any significant change on the BIOS before), but I tried the other way round.

This problem was triggered when my virtual memory got overloaded, so I guess it makes sense it was solved when no energy was given to my laptop to keep anything in it. 
Until now I thought rebooting a computer was enough to clean the memory, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for not detecting Wifi after new installations or such issues might be a problem with Network Adapter Drivers.

You can first check which Wifi Network Adapter is there in your PC.

```
lshw -C network
```

Mine Wireless N/W adapter was Realtek rtl8723be. So I installed the drivers from :

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

Thanks.